# Advantages of Cinnamon for UI test automation

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, test-automation, selenium

We want to start automating our UI tests and have found [Cinnamon](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cinnamon) that seems to be a better and more specific Salesforce testing tool. We want to use a testing tool for our managed package that has custom Visualforce pages and want to know what benefits Cinnamon offers for UI test automation.

Comment: I don't think Cinnamon supports lightning, as I can see it was last modified 3 years ago.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal That seems to be right. We're only interested in Visualforce testing functionality but it may impact others.

Comment: It looks like Cinnamon is built *on top of* Selenium, no?

Comment: Yeah. Which is why I'm asking the question to see if it makes sense to use it or just use Selenium directly.

Comment: Questions which ask *which tool is better* or asking for pros/cons are often opinion based and quite broad. This information may be valuable to the Salesforce community, but doesn't really fit the format here. You may wish to ask on a *forum*, which this site is not. From what I understand, the developer boards are much more accepting of this format.

Comment: This question is still unlikely to be reopened. What are you trying to understand that is not covered in the documentation? Your question is still not very specific.

Comment: The documentation is mostly weak and old. I mostly want to know if it is being used by active members of the community and has any proven benefits. The fact that no one has commented on the library itself may be my answer...